# Bad CMake executable "". Is it installed or settings contain the correct path (cmake.cmakePath)? - Pixhawk 4 Development

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, path, cygwin

I want to complete the setup in Visual Studio Code for Pixhawk 4 development. So I followed the steps given in this documentation below. I also installed the Cygwin Toolchain previously.

https://dev.px4.io/master/en/setup/vscode.html

After opening the Firmware folder in vsc, I installed all recommended extensions. Then I selected the kit and clicked on build using the blue bar in the bottom to configure the project. Right after that, I got this error:

*Bad CMake executable "". Is it installed or settings contain the correct path (cmake.cmakePath)?*

What might be causing the problem? I am a beginner so if anything is unclear about the question please ask me for it. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Do you have cmake on your platform? If not, you have to download it (https://cmake.org/install/), If you do have it, it could be that the binary is corrupt, in which case I would re-install it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I updated `VSCode`. In the project setting I put the full path of `Cmake` like:

```json
"cmake.cmakePath": "/usr/local/bin/cmake"
```

And it worked.

Comment: For me the path was `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake`. You can get your path using `where cmake`

Comment: In Ubuntu, the command would be `whereis cmake`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and could solve it by (re)installing `cmake`:

```bash
sudo apt install cmake
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with the path having a space in it apparently. Lots of people have run into this, but it has yet to be fixed (I just hit it myself earlier today). The "solution" (read: workaround...because Microsoft... ) is to reinstall Cmake in a different directory (one with no spaces, obviously ), and to [ensure that it is in your system path](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/).

[See this Github issue for extensive troubleshooting/discussion.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/685)

Answer (score 0):

If gcc is not installed, you need to install gcc first and then install cmake.

1. install gcc

   sudo apt install build-essential
2. Download CMake from https://cmake.org/download/
3. Install CMake

   $ ./bootstrap

   $ make

   $ make install

After this step try again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the C++ extensions from VS Code and install them again. It worked for me in this case =)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).